# Combobox and JButton issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, combobox, jbutton

I have been playing about with a GUI today and trying add different elements to it,

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == jButton1)                              
        {
            //Do Something
        }

        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String petName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();

        if(petName == "Cat")
        {
            //Do Something
        }

   }
```

When i click jButton1 it does what i want it to do and when i select "Cat" from the combobox it does what i want it to do, but only when i click jButton1 and not when i select cat it gives me the following error

> javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComboBox

Any ideas obviously something to do with the comboxbox code and when i remove the code from JCombobox down  the error doesnt appear.

Any help would be good, not homework just be messing about and seeing if i can learn new things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, don't compare strings using `==`, use the `equals` method. That is, change

```
petName == "Cat"
```

to

```
petName.equals("Cat")
```

(`==` compares references, not the objects the references refer to)

Related question:

- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

---

Regarding the "JButton cannot be cast to JComboBox"-issue, it seems to me like you're simply forgetting an `else` there. Try the following:

```
if (e.getSource() == jButton1) {
    //Do Something
} else {

    JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    String petName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();

    if(petName == "Cat") {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

(or simply `return` from the method once you're done with the `Do something` related to the JButton.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice regards == and .equals, should have spotted that one, as for the else its still giving me the error when i add this.

Comment: The error is due to the fact that `e.getSource()` returns a `JButton`. In other words, the error occurs when the source of the event is a `JButton` and you insist on trying to cast it to a `JComboBox`. Have a look at your program logic and try to figure out the origin of the event, and make sure you don't try to cast it to a `JComboBox` if it may come from a `JButton`.

Comment: Would this issue be around this  jButton1.addActionListener(this);
 petList.addActionListener(this); in the constructor

Comment: Could be. Try wrapping the combo-box specific stuff in `if (e.getSource() == theComboBox) { ... }` to make sure you're not trying to cast the `e.getSource()` into an `JComboBox` without knowing you should.